# How do you add integer iterations together

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function prints a pyramid made of "*" and "&" characters.  I want the program to print out the total number of "&" characters in the pyramid, so I used .count to count how many times "&" appears in each row.  The problem is that I can't sum together the output from variable z to get the total time "&" appears in the pyramid.  Any ideas?

```
import random
from random import choice
from random import randint

def pyramid():
    min_pyramid_size = 5
    max_pyramid_size = 10
    num_rows = random.randint(min_pyramid_size, max_pyramid_size)
    for i in range(num_rows):
        x = ''.join(str(random.choice('*&')) for j in range(2*i+1))
        print(' ' * (num_rows - i) + x)
        z = x.count('&')
        print(z)

pyramid()
```

UPDATE:
I tried moving z out of the loop and it just prints the number of "&" in the last row.

```
import random
from random import choice
from random import randint

def pyramid():
    min_pyramid_size = 3
    max_pyramid_size = 5
    num_rows = random.randint(min_pyramid_size, max_pyramid_size)
    for i in range(num_rows):
        x = ''.join(str(random.choice('*&')) for j in range(2*i+1))
        print(' ' * (num_rows - i) + x)
    z = 0
    z += x.count('&')
    print(z)

pyramid()
```

Comment: not this way.. see the answer i replied below. it was working for me

Answer (score 2):

Haven't run it, but you need a variable outside the for loop that will hold the total number of '&'s.

```
def pyramid():
    min_pyramid_size = 5
    max_pyramid_size = 10
    num_rows = random.randint(min_pyramid_size, max_pyramid_size)
    total_z = 0
    for i in range(num_rows):
        x = ''.join(str(random.choice('*&')) for j in range(2*i+1))
        print(' ' * (num_rows - i) + x)
        z = x.count('&')
        total_z = total_z + z
        print(z)

pyramid()
```

Answer (score 0):

define z outside the scope of the for loop

```
z = 0
```

and use

```
z += x.count('&')
```

rather than

```
z = x.count('&')
```

Comment: I gave that a shot, and it just prints the number of "&" in the last row?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
import random
from random import choice
from random import randint

def pyramid():
    min_pyramid_size = 5
    max_pyramid_size = 10
    z = 0
    num_rows = random.randint(min_pyramid_size, max_pyramid_size)
    for i in range(num_rows):
        x = ''.join(str(random.choice('*&')) for j in range(2*i+1))
        print(' ' * (num_rows - i) + x)
        z = z + x.count('&')
    print(z)

pyramid()
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I just had to move print(z) outside the loop and your solution works great.

Comment: ya true, putting print(z) outside the for would avoid printing z at the end of each iteration. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more compact solution using a list comprehension:

```
def pyramid(min_size=5, max_size=10):
    N = randint(min_size, max_size)
    x = ''.join(' ' * (N-i) + ''.join(choice('*&') for j in range(2*i+1)) + '\n' for i in range(N))
    print(x)
    print(x.count('&'))
```

Demo:

```
>>>  pyramid()
         &
        &*&
       &**&*
      &&&**&*
     &***&&&&&
    &&&&*&&****
   &&&&*&***&&**
  *&&&&**&&&&&**&
 &*&***&*&&&*&&*&*

47
```

You could change the values of the minimum and maximum size of the pyramid by passing the appropriate arguments to the function, for example `pyramid(min_size=8, max_size=12)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two variables, one for the internal and one for the external count.

```
def pyramid():
  min_pyramid_size = 5
  max_pyramid_size = 10
  num_rows = random.randint(min_pyramid_size, max_pyramid_size)
  outer_z = 0
  for i in range(num_rows):
    x = ''.join(str(random.choice('*&')) for j in range(2*i+1))
    print(' ' * (num_rows - i) + x)
    inner_z = x.count('&')  # Alternatively calculate inner_z twice, but don't store it:
    print(inner_z)          # print(x.count('&'))
    outer_z += inner_z      # outer_z += x.count('&')
  print(outer_z)
```